# Я хочу запарсить сайт погоды, но python выдаёт ошибку при установке библиотеки

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

То, что я ввёл:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2019. Все права защищены.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install BeautifullSoup
Collecting BeautifullSoup
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement BeautifullSoup (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for BeautifullSoup
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install beautifullsoup
Collecting beautifullsoup
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifullsoup (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for beautifullsoup
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

ошибка:

```
Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: Как именно делаешь установку? Выложи весь лог, который появляется в консоли.

Comment: Я делал и через pycharm и через cmd, в cmd вот так: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement BeautifullSoup (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for BeautifullSoup

Comment: Сделай еще раз через cmd, скопируй все, что будет в консоли. От строки, где ты вводишь команду, до новой строки с приглашением ввода команды. Внеси все это в сам вопрос, отредактировав его и добавив указанный мной текст.

Comment: Сделал, выводит тоже самое

Comment: pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Он установился, но всё равно выходит ошибка в программе

Comment: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: А для решения этого вопроса есть хороший ответ прямо на этом же сайте. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398302/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste
Может стоит начать пользоваться поиском?

Comment: Я установил lxml, но он всё равно пишет тоже самое

Comment: @Super попробуйте `pip install lxml` и `pip install bs4`, дальше в коде уже `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

Проверять команды установки нужно на сайте репозитория https://pypi.org/

[В поиске репозитория](https://pypi.org/search/?q=beautifulsoup) находится 2 библиотеки с таким названием. В частности [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/) и [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). Если посмотреть страницу первой библиотеки, то можно увидеть дикслеймер:

> You should use the `beautifulsoup4` package instead of this package.

А так же указание на то, что данная библиотека поддерживает только Python 2.7.

Подозреваю, что у тебя стоит все таки Python 3.x, и pip тебе сообщает, что не нашел версии библиотеки под твою версию Python. Как верно указал [Vadim.Sharoikin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/355827/vadim-sharoikin) и как указано в описании библиотеки `BeautifulSoup`, нужно использовать новую версию - beautifulsoup4.

Comment: Это не помогло, моя программа всё равно пишет Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Вы очень невнимательно читаете текст ошибки. Он не тот же самый. Теперь нет парсера xml, а до этого не было lxml

Comment: У меня после установки lxml все заработало.

```Выбирайте город из перечисленных и запишите его:
Москва, Ульяновск, Хабаровск, Минск
Минск
В Минске +26°. Ощущается как +29°. Через час будет +26°.
```

Проверте, не было ли внесено изменений в код

Comment: Да, я немного поменял код, но сейчас вернул всё как было и он выводит соответствующую ошибку  '''Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?''' Хотя я установил  и bs4 и lxml, но выдаёт ошибку при установке beautifullsoup4  и код не работает!

Comment: Выложите текущий код на https://pastebin.com/ или подобном ресурсе. Скиньте сюда ссылку